# Python how to remove the first set of a character in a string?

Tags: python-3.x

My variable `x` has a value of `"000032403"` and I want to remove the first set of zeros but I want to keep the other! How I gonna do that?

Note: Please give me any suggestions without knowing the amount of zeros in the beginning, because in my program this value is obtained from the user.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lstrip()` function of the string class like this

```
>>> x = "000032403"
>>> x.lstrip("0")
"32403"
```

This will "return a copy of the string with leading characters removed".

[Here's a link to the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip)